# Prepending character(s) to a custom <!--more--> tag title?

Tags: filters, tags, hooks, read-more, quicktag

I'm hacking around with a blog using Cordobo Green Park and I've noticed when I specify a custom  title, instead of it beginning with a `»` symbol (as it does for the standard "*» Read more: [POSTTITLE]*") the custom message is simply shown without any prepended character. It's a shame, because the » character would be nice to include for visual consistency.

In `./themes/cordobo/index.php` (lines 28-30) there's this piece of code which I think handles the  tag:

```
<div class="entry">
   <?php the_content((__( '&raquo; Read more: ', 'default')) . the_title('', '', false)); ?>
</div>
```

Which differs from [the Codex example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content) with no 'default' second variable:

```
<?php the_content("Continue reading " . the_title('', '', false)); ?>
```

*Never mind my puzzlement over the `__(` after the initial double opening brackets (the Codex doesn't really have anything of help to me for explaining this - any takers?)* ... I just can't figure out how to simply prepend the `»` character to custom `<!--more-->` text.

I'm just tying myself in knots here, but I *think* the actual crux of adding a prepended character(s) to custom  titles is modifying the action of the regex-detecting-then-variable-setting function of get_the_content inside `post-template.php` ([line 203](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L203)):

```
$more_link_text = strip_tags(wp_kses_no_null(trim($matches[1])));
```

However, what's the best (non-destructive, and upgrade-proof) way to override the default behaviour of that subroutine and define a customised version of `$more_link_text`? I really don't want to go destructively hacking core files, but I struggle with coding filters so at the moment it's still looking tempting.

Comment: __() is a function for translation. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question - if so apologies!

```
&raquo;
```

represents the `»` symbol.

I think all you need to do is add it into your second example, if that's what's displaying in your template:

```
<?php the_content("&raquo; Continue reading " . the_title('', '', false)); ?>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite what I meant - what I'm trying to do is prepend a &raquo; onto the **custom** `<!--more-->` text (when specified) - so if I specified `<!--more There's more after the jump... -->` WP would output "`» There's more after the jump...`" instead of just the text on its own. The &raquo; is added by default, I suspect by the template, but Green Park is a nonimally unsupported theme from Cordobo and the way the Loop's being used and the framework's being loaded is mindbogglingly complex to me!